# javascript: What is a flow disable line?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Reading the code of Vue.js I found this:

```
function isPrimitive (value) {
  return (
    typeof value === 'string' ||
    typeof value === 'number' ||
    // $flow-disable-line
    typeof value === 'symbol' ||
    typeof value === 'boolean'
  )
}
```

What is the purpose of the // $flow-disable-line comment? Does it alter in any way the evaluation?

Comment: A google search for `$flow-disable-line` indicates that it disables Flow JS error reporting on the following line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**What is it**

You will notice in the repo that there is a [.flowconfig](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/.flowconfig#L23) with the following option:

```
suppress_comment= \\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$flow-disable-line
```

Which seems to be a way to disable errors for the next line in Flow JS

**Why does Vue use it**

From [flows documentation](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/primitives/#toc-symbols):

> Symbols are not currently supported by Flow. You can see these two issues for more information (see link)

So since flow doesn't support symbols, and vue needs to utilize symbols, it only makes sense to disable errors on the line using them.

Hope this helps!